Weird typing issues at Ubuntu 24
I have katana msi GF 66 12 UD.
I had Ubuntu 22 installed earlier and today even upgraded to Ubuntu 24, but the issue is not resolved. Issue is my system has started behaving werird, It automatically switches to another tab and even when I am typing it automatically deletes words or goes to random position in text tab. I am not sure how to resolve this ?
Also, another issue is I cant access my camera
